# Android Studio not correctly rendering font on Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio

Below is the picture of Android Studio when I first installed it:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Oracle Java 7. But the fonts are looking very ugly. They are not looking like they look when I see them on eclipse.

Earlier when I installed NetBeans, I had same problem too.

Comment: Caution: Android Studio is currently available as an early access preview. Several features are either incomplete or not yet implemented and you may encounter bugs. If you are not comfortable using an unfinished product, you may want to instead download (or continue to use) the ADT Bundle (Eclipse with the ADT Plugin).

Comment: I'm already using eclipse. I just wanted to know perhaps there is a process like there was a process to solve the same problem in NetBeans... Anyhow, Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried several suggested tweaks, tried using FontFix Patched JDK, FontForge, and editing studio.vmoptions; though some of these could show some improvement, it does not come close to the font rendering quality of the non-swing apps like eclipse.

I've found this to be the easiest and cleanest solution:

```
rm -r ~/.AndroidStudioBeta
```

If you have installed openjdk-fontfix, or made changes to studio.vmoptions, it is better you revert back those changes to their defaults.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/openjdk-fontfix
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 sudo ppa-purge ppa:no1wantdthisname/openjdk-fontfix
```

Remove all custom-added JAVA environment variables ($JAVA_HOME, $PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin). Check in files, `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.pam_environment`

Install the latest Oracle Java via launchpad ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

This ppa installer will usually do more than what a manual JDK configuration will do.

[[image: Fix Font Rendering, Android Studio, Inte]]

Monospaced fonts like 'Inconsolata' and 'Source Code Pro' works best for me.

Comment: @BornToCode Did you try with the default Adobe Source Code Pro font?

Comment: No, I use Ubuntu Mono. I am not sure using Adobe Source Code Pro will make the appearance better.

Comment: @BornToCode I think it's patched, and comes pre-installed with AS. So give it a go.

Comment: @reversiblean - OK, I remove .AndroidStudioBeta, and Android Studio won't start.

Comment: This is not as good as Eclipse, but for me `openjdk-fontfix` is worse. So, let's go with Oracle JDK and Source Code Pro font.

Answer (score 25):

There actually is a solution. You need to install JDK font fix as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/openjdk-fontfix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Then, open studio.vmoptions and optionally studio64.vmoptions in your android-studio/bin directory, and add following lines to both of them (the first one might be already there):

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
```

After you reboot, the font rendering is just fine. To get the most Eclipse-like experience, go to File, Settings, Editor, Colors & Fonts, Font. Save the current scheme as a new one, and change the font to "Monospaced" with size of 14.

Comment: Wait a minute, In Android Studio, we are recommended to use Oracle's Java. Hence, I removed Open JDK and then installed Oracle's Java. Anyhow, I'm re-installing it. Hope it will work!

Comment: It works for me, but who knows, I may run into issues later. However, you need to use the repository above to get the font fix.

Comment: This actually fixes the problem. But OpenJDK is slower than Oracle's JDK

Comment: There's antialiasing, but it's still not as good as in Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to install OpenJDK or the above-mentioned fix .deb for correct font rendering. Simply launch the Studio with:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true' path/to/studio.sh
```

.. and fonts should render right under Ubuntu with Oracle's JDK 7. Looks even better when you change theme to GTK+ under File -> Settings -> Appearance.

Answer (score 3):

In **studio.sh**, find this line at the bottom of the file:

```
eval "$JDK/bin/java" $ALL_JVM_ARGS -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.restart.code=88 $MAIN_CLASS_NAME "$@"
```

and change it to

```
eval "$JDK/bin/java" $ALL_JVM_ARGS -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Djb.restart.code=88 $MAIN_CLASS_NAME "$@"
```

This means changing the parameter

**-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd** (if present)

to

**-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on**

Or simply add this param if you don't have it.

Comment: There is no such line. It's in studio64.vmoptions, but it doesn't either there.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is configure the fonts in the settings as follows:
File > Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Font

In that screen then you save a new scheme clicking in Save as, and putting a name on it, lets say "Custom".

Then below you'll find all the settings you need, you can tweak the font family and the size as well.

Comment: This is off-topic. He does not want to change the profile or a font, the problem is that this friggin' Android studio uses the default Java font settings which are not antialiased.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 1.2 Preview 1 has been released a few hours ago (Mar 9th 2015):
http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio12preview1

> It also includes several really important fixes that have been requested by Android Studio users, such as high density (retina) support for Windows and Linux.

It is based on **IntelliJ IDEA 14.1**, and according to the [IntelliJ release notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP), includes "**The HiDPI support for Windows/Linux (scaled icons/font-size, no blur)**".

However, I tried this on my machine (Ubuntu 14.10), and could not see any improvements. Maybe someone else has information on how to make it work?

Comment: If it doesn't give any improvements why do you mentioned it here?

Comment: @VishnudevK Because it might for you? Or someone else who is using Windows? It sounded like this is directly related to the blurry fonts.